# Reportando - Ícone de aviso de Posts aguardando revisão com valor errado

Tags: suporte, filas-de-análise

O ícone de aviso de Posts aguardando revisão com valor errado, está indicando uma quantidade de posts aguardando revisão e quando acesso a área de revisão ela está vazia, atualizei inúmeras vezes e o erro persistiu, ele também é intermitente e as vezes indica um numero alto como 8 e na área de revisão tem 3 posts e novamente atualizo a pagina e continua o problema, outro detalhe o title está em inglês.

Comment: [Contador de sugestões de edição está incoerente](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1282/4808).